# How do I display public text in Activity A after it has been changed by Activity B

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

This probably demonstrates the most appalling lack of understanding of the activity life cycle, but please be sympathetic. I am ultimately going to want to invoke `Activity B` from `Activity A` a number of times, each time passing a different parameter to `Activity B` which is then responded to by the user and stores/sets various public variables. As a precursor to this, I just want to get my head round how `Activity A` sees the change to a public variable that `Activity B` has changed.

I have three very simple classes: `Common.java` that holds the public variables, the main activity `MainActivity.java` and the child activity `Child.java`. There is only one public variable right now; it's the string `mess1` which is initialized to `"***"`. All the code does at the moment is when `mainbutton` is clicked in `MainActivity`, it invokes `Child`. In `Child`, we immediately set `mess1` to `"Child here"` then set the text in a `Child`-based `TextView` to `mess1`. On clicking the `childbtn` button in `Child`, we `finish()` the child activity (and of course the system returns us to `MainActivity`.

When this app is run, wee see the three stars displayed in `MainActivity`. When `mainbutton` is pressed we go to `Child` and see `"Child here"` displayed. When the `childbtn` is pressed, we return to `MainActivity` BUT, the three stars are still there although we know for sure that `mess1` now holds `"Child here"`.

My questions are:
1. Why, when we know `mess1` has been changed, does `MainActivity` still display `"***"` on return from the `Child` activity?
2. What do I need to change in the code to get `"Child here"` to display?

Relevant code extracts follow. Thanks in advance for your help.

**Common.java**

```
public class Common
{
    public static String mess1 = "***";
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button mainbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainbutton);
    TextView maintop = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.maintop);

    mainbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Child.class));
        }
    });

    maintop.setText(Common.mess1);
}
```

**Child.java**

```
public class Child extends AppCompatActivity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);

    TextView childtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.childtext);
    final Button childbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.childbtn);

    Common.mess1 = "Child here";
    childtext.setText(Common.mess1);

    childbtn.setOnClickListener
            (new View.OnClickListener()
             {public void onClick(View v)
                 {finish();
                 }
             }
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the text in `onResume()` of `MainActivity`. When you get back from `Child.java` `onResume()` (not `onCreate()`) is invoked and, since `maintop`'s text is set in `onCerate()` only, nothing changes it on return.

```
protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();

     maintop.setText(Common.mess1);
 }
```

Reference: [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and [Implementing the lifecycle callbacks](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks)

Comment: Acceptance done, Onik. Perhaps you could help with my next post (just posted now), namely "In Android Studio, cannot invoke Activity B from Activity A more than once".

Answer (score 2):

Likely you are moving back on the back stack history and you are resuming the previous activity that was placed in a paused state and therefore the onCreate isn't being called but the onResume (of the initial activity)..

Using global state this way isn't advised but this should work if you place the appropriate code in the onResume method.